# Using ui-router with ngTouch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm making an Angular.js site using UI-Router. However I also need ngTouch to eliminate the 300ms touch delay on devices..

Ui-router recommends you use the ui-sref directive to navigate.  ngTouch only affects ngClick.

Is there a recommended way to fix this?  A new directive? A scope function that calls $state.go?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using hammerjs for handling touch events.

[Angular-hammer](https://github.com/dreame4/angular-hammer)https://github.com/dreame4/angular-hammer

[Hammerjs website](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/)

These are the mobile sites we are currently using hammerjs + angular:

[Site 1](http://m.pontofrio.com.br) and [Site 2](http://m.casasbahia.com.br)